# How to differentiate between touch and mouse in WndProc in C# WinForms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

We are working on providing touch resizing support for our control in WinForms and our requirement was to show the touch resizing PopUp when touching the app and closing the PopUp when an `MouseUp` or `MouseDown` event occurs.

We can differ the touch by using the constant value `WM_GESTURE = 0x0119`, but `PointerUp` and `PointerDown` are also becoming `TRUE` when touched and we're not able to differ the mouse touch from the other events.

Is there any way to specifically identify the mouse?

```
switch (m.Msg)
{                
    case WM_TOUCH:
        IsTouchEnabled = true;
        break;
    case WM_POINTERUP:
        IsTouchEnabled = false;
        break;
    case WM_POINTERDOWN:
        IsTouchEnabled = false;
        break;
 }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can differentiate the touch down and mouse down by using **GetMessageExtraInfo** method like below.

```
    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("IsTouch: " + IsTouch());
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
    }

    public bool IsTouch()
    {
        uint extra = GetMessageExtraInfo();
        bool isTouchOrPen = ((extra & 0xFFFFFF00) == 0xFF515700);

        if (!isTouchOrPen)
            return false;

        bool isTouch = ((extra & 0x00000080) == 0x00000080);

        return isTouch;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern uint GetMessageExtraInfo();
```

Comment: Hi, the calls to GetMessageExtraInfo is managed code or unmanaged code ? I just want to be sure that this code does not introduce memory leak